# How to install a library on a runner? Continous Integration and GitLab

Tags: c++, continuous-integration, shared-libraries, gitlab

I am trying to configure the continuous integration on GitLab. My .gitlab-ci.yml looks like this:

```
image: gcc
before_script:
  - curl http://libmodbus.org/releases/libmodbus-3.1.2.tar.gz | tar xvz
  - cd ./libmodbus-3.1.2/
  - ./configure -prefix=/ust $$ make $$ make install
  - cd ..
build:
  stage: build

  script: 
    - make

test:
  stage: test
  script:

    - ./bin/Test
```

And I need the library "LibModBus 3.1.2" built on the runner. How can it be done?

Solved! Changed the script to install the library like showed

Comment: Do you need to **install** the lib or **build** it?

Comment: In a normal environment I would download the tarball, decompress it and run './configure', 'make' and 'make install'. 
But I don't know if its the way to do it on Shared runners provided by gitlab

Comment: Looks like you use docker. If you use docker your decscribed route is totally valid. IF you would have used a shell runner this method would be problematic. Just use a `before_script` to install dependencies.

Comment: I have used the before_script to install the library in the 'build' stage, grep the library, untar it, configure, make and make install...But when the test stage starts it doesn't find the library showing me this error:

    ./bin/adam6015Test: error while loading shared libraries: libmodbus.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Have you tried a global `before_script`?

Comment: Yes, and what it does is doing the script before build and test stage but if I do a - ldconfig -p to show the libs installed I can't see it installed. I modified the question to show the actual configuration file